# Add a custom button in WordPress register form

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I am trying to add a button in wordpress register form but the position of button is not right as i want. It is looking like the below image
[image]

But i want it something like this
[image]

Given below is my code

```
public function init()
{
   global $mySetting;
   $mySetting = get_option('my_options');
   add_action('register_form', [$this, 'my_registration_button']);
   add_action('login_form', [$this, 'my_registration_button']);
}

public function my_registration_button()
{
?>
    <p><a href="#" class="button button-primary">My Button</a></p>
<?php
}
```

Comment: did you tried applying float:left for the my button?

Comment: yes but no luck

Comment: by seeing only image, its hard to do a trial and error from solution end. Its better to post css and html of that registration form

Comment: I tried the css but currently no css in the code.